# How to Make Relative Href Work in SvelteKit?

Tags: href, svelte, sveltekit

I want to build a Web app with SvelteKit with one page listing all items (with potential search query parameters), and then one page for each individual item. If I had to build this the old school way with everything generated in the backend, my paths would be `/items/` for the list of all items, and `/items/123` for item `123`, etc. That is, to go to the page of item `123`, a link will with `href="123"` will work no matter if you are currently at the index (`/items/`) or at the page of one particular item (`/items/[id]`).

With SvelteKit, if I create files `routes/items/index.svelte` and `routes/items/[id].svelte`, then `routes/items/index.svelte` will have path `/items`, **without** a trailing slash, and as a result a link with `href="123"` will lead to `/123`, resulting in a "not found" error.

This same link will work however from the page of an individual item, say, `/items/456`.

This is radically different from what you would have in the traditional HTML model, where a link from `/items/` (or `/items/index.html`) would work the same as a link from `/items/[id].html`.

Now in `svelte.config.js` there is a `trailingSlash` option you can set to `always` so that `routes/items/index.svelte` corresponds to path `/items/`, but then `routes/items/[id].svelte` has path `/items/[id]/` and we have the same problem again: one `href` value cannot work from both the index and the page of an individual item.

The only way I see right now is to use absolute path, but it's not very composable. My guess is that there is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Question: would it help to have the base path for the href as a prop with a default value, and then concatenate the ID to it dynamically inside the component to generate the href? You could then pass in an optional prop to change the base path as needed, but have the most common case set by default.

Comment: @NikP yes, as long as relative paths cannot work (see accepted answer) I'm going to have to go for something like what you describe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything - it's not currently possible in SvelteKit to have a trailing slash for some pages but not for others. There is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1405) you may be interested in that proposes adding additional `trailingSlash` options. This issue cites the exact problem you described:

> The trailingSlash options introduced in #1404 don't make it straightforward to add trailing slashes to index pages but not to leaf pages. For example you might want to have /blog/ and /blog/some-post rather than /blog and /blog-some-post, since that allows the index page to contain relative links.

Until that feature is added, you'll need to use absolute paths.

Comment: October 2023 update: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1405 is now closed after the problem was solved by moving the `trailingSlash` option from the Svelte config file to each individual Svelte page: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/7719